# What to retrieve week-wise no. of accounts opened in last month data

Tags: sql-server, group-by, datepart

I What to retrieve week-wise no. of accounts opened in last month data.
example:- In april month's 1st week 2 accounts are opened like wise.
what will be the syntax

I have tried this query but its showing week no. 9 but i want week no. 1 of april month

```
select datepart(ww,doo) as 'Week No.', count(*) as 'No. of Account'
from accountmaster
where datediff(mm,doo,getdate())=1
group by datepart(ww,doo)
```

Comment: `datepart (week)` gives you week no of the year. Please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments) for further details

Comment: You can play around with datediff(day, '20230401',yourday)/7+1

Comment: @siggemannen Its works thnx

Comment: FYI, syntax like `where datediff(mm,doo,getdate())=1` isn't SARGable. Use a date *range*. Also, I really recommend using actual names of your periods, `MINUTE`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, etc, rather than the abbreviations; it's *much* easier for you and others to read.  I've seen multiple people use `m` (or `mm`) for *minutes* and wonder why it's not working as they expect.